# Arduino convert constant char to unsigned long

Tags: variables, arduino

I'm asking you to know how to convert a constant char variable[] to a unsigned long variable!

The problem doesn't exist if not for :

I've to convert this value for example "0x20DF10EF" if I convert it to long it return me back "551489775".

What i want is to receive back "0x20DF10EF"!

Hope i've explained well enough my problem!

Best regards D.Tibe!

---- Edit ----

```
         while(O != 'I'){              
          if(reciver.decode(&results)){
            CMD[i] = "0x" + String(results.value, HEX);
            CMD[i].toUpperCase();
            Val[0] = CMD[i].c_str();

            //Vil[0] = CMD[i].c_str();
            //for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(Val[0])-1 ;i++)
            //{
            //}

            Byte = String(results.bits, DEC);
            delay(1000);
            O = 'I';
            reciver.resume();
          }
```

This is my code!
I have to convert my Val[0] (that is a Constant char) to Unsigned long variable.

Like said before i'll have a value like this 0x20DF10EF in my constant char and i want to get exactly the same on my unsigned long variable, SO :

Val[0] will be = to 0x20DF10EF and i want to get back the same value but into the unsigned long variable like this

unsigned long Var will be = to 0x20DF10EF

Comment: Well, 0x20DF10EF *is* in fact 551489775. I don't quite get your question.

Comment: "Arduino" is not C or pure C++. And SO is no coding service. Show your code and state where exactly your problem is.

Comment: i've re-explained better my question editing the main post!

Comment: I still don't get it. An `unsigned long` with the value 0x20DF10EF is exactly the same as an `unsigned long` with the value 551489775. It's the same number in two different bases.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is there!
Like I said i don't be able to get an `unsigned long` with the `0x20DF10EF` because i have that value into a `char variable` i want that my char variable is converted to a unsigned long.
So you said that is the same but with two different bases!
How can i converte (Keeping the HEX base) a char 0x20DF10EF into an unsigned long (HEX) 0x20DF10EF???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to parse a `const char *` string with an hex number and put it into a variable.

If this is correct, there are two ways: using the `sscanf` function or converting it by hand.

Method 1:

```
unsigned long result;

if (sscanf(Val[0], "0x%x", &result) != 1)
{
    Serial.println("Val[0] is not a valid hex value");
}
```

Method 2:

```
unsigned long result = 0;
byte i;

for (i = 2; i < strlen(Val[0]); i++)
{
    if ((Val[0][i] >= '0') && (Val[0][i] <= '9'))
    {
        result = (result << 4) + Val[0][i] - '0';
    }
    else if ((Val[0][i] >= 'A') && (Val[0][i] <= 'F'))
    {
        result = (result << 4) + 10 + Val[0][i] - 'A';
    }
    else if ((Val[0][i] >= 'a') && (Val[0][i] <= 'f'))
    {
        result = (result << 4) + 10 + Val[0][i] - 'a';
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Val[0] is not a valid hex value");
        break;
    }
}
```

By the way, adding `0x` in front of the string is useless for this conversion. If you can, remove it and then replace `"0x%x"` with `"%x"` in the sscanf solution, or `i = 2` with `i = 0` in the hand-made one.

Comment: Yeah thanks!! I found the solution yesterday using "unsigned long int" and not "unsigned long" but I have only one problem it convert my value into the same HEX value but without the 0x, I need to add also the 0x but if I try to do it manually it give me an error that says "x is a character" how can I add the 0x? Naturally always on unsigned long int variable!! Thanks a lot for the answer!!!

Comment: Wait, WHERE do you want to add it? To the string? If so just prepend it. If not show an example of the code that doesn't work. Then if this answer solves your problem mark it as solved

Comment: Ok man, sorry I'll explain better now!

Now i'm able to convert my variable like this : 

String a = 0x20DF10EF;

unsigned long int b  = strtoul(a, NULL, 16);

This work and convert my String variable to unsigned long int but....
The result of conversion is without the 0x like this 20DF10EF;

So i want to add into the unsigned long int the 0x initial; how can i do it?

And i don't know if i marked answered the right way. Is my first time in forum!

Thanks for all!

Comment: 0x is just a prefix that, in strings, is used conventionally to indicate that the number is expressed in hexadecimal format. But just in strings! your b variable contains 20DF10EF (in hex) = 551489775 (decimal) = 4067610357 (octal) = 100000110111110001000011101111 (binary). All these representation are THE SAME, exactly like when you say that the animal is a "dog", or a "DOG", or even a "chien", or "cane". The animal is always the same. If you write `a = 10; b = 0xA; c = 0b1010;` the three variables will be EXACTLY the same. The 0x comes when you want to convert these variables in string.

Comment: So, if you want to write your `b` variable using `printf`, for instance, you can write `printf("0x%x", b);` and you will get `0x20DF10EF`; you have to add it "by hand, though. But again, that is not even stored in the variable. If you write a number in a different base, the program will not be able to notice it (even because all numbers are converted to binary for storage). PS. yes, you marked it correctly ;)

Comment: Ok, i understand what u said but...

This is my code 

for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++){
        //irsend.sendNEC(0x20DF10EF , 32);
        irsend.sendNEC((CH[0], HEX) , 32);
        delay(100);
      }

in CH[0] have to be write 0xetcc.....
but... I have only the hexadecimal value without 0x, I need the 0x because don't work in other value!!!

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++){ 
//irsend.sendNEC(0x20DF10EF , 32); 
irsend.sendNEC((CH[0], HEX) , 32); delay(100); 
}`

Ok so CH[0] is my 'unsigned long int' variable and contains the value 20DF10EF...
I want to send the variable like the commented piece of code '0x20DF10EF'!
 With '0x20DF10EF' it works but without not! So I only want to the 0x value in front the value!
Can you tell me how can i do that??

Comment: Well, `0x20DF10EF` means "create a variable and put inside it the value 20DF10EF". So for the compiler `irsend.sendNEC(0x20DF10EF , 32);` and `CH[0] = 0x20DF10EF; irsend.sendNEC(CH[0] , 32);` are exactly the same. Now, in your code you wrote `(CH[0], HEX)`, which means nothing. Just write `irsend.sendNEC(CH[0] , 32);` and it should work. Remember that an integer DOES NOT have info on what base it is - in fact, the base is always binary.

Comment: Wonderful.. Just remember, the base is something beyond the integer: it's  just a way to represent it.. ;)